# Using GADTs with DataKinds for type level data constructor constraints in functions

Tags: haskell, gadt, existential-type, data-kinds

I'm trying to use a GADT with DataKinds, as shown below

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, GADTs #-}
module NewGadt where

data ExprType = Var | Nest

data Expr (a :: ExprType) where
  ExprVar :: String -> Expr Var
  ExprNest :: Expr a -> Expr Nest

data BaseExpr
  = BaseExprVar String
  | BaseExprNest BaseExpr

translate :: BaseExpr -> Expr a
translate (BaseExprVar id) = ExprVar id
translate (BaseExprNest expr) = ExprNest $ translate expr
```

Compile error:

```
/home/elijah/code/monty/src/NewGadt.hs:15:32: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘'Var’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          bexprToExpr :: forall (a :: ExprType). BaseExpr -> Expr a
        at src/NewGadt.hs:14:1-33
      Expected type: Expr a
        Actual type: Expr 'Var
    • In the expression: ExprVar id
      In an equation for ‘bexprToExpr’:
          bexprToExpr (BaseExprVar id) = ExprVar id
    • Relevant bindings include
        bexprToExpr :: BaseExpr -> Expr a (bound at src/NewGadt.hs:15:1)
   |
15 | bexprToExpr (BaseExprVar id) = ExprVar id
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I would like to do this so certain functions can only work on a specific type of expr, for example:

```hs
printVariable :: Expr Var -> IO ()
printVariable (ExprVar id) = putStrLn id

printNested :: Expr Nest -> IO ()
printNested (ExprNest inner) = putStrLn "nested expression"

printExpr :: Expr a -> IO ()
printExpr expr@ExprVar {} = printVariable expr
printExpr expr@ExprNest {} = printNested expr
```

And of course, calling `printVariable` with an `Expr Nest` should fail compilation.

Is there a way I can have the translate function return `Expr a` like this? Or is this an inappropriate usage of DataKinds & GADTs?

Edit:

Solution worked! But, I had to upgrade to ghc >=8.10 and enable `StandaloneKindSignatures, PolyKinds`

Comment: In the future the answer will be [`translate :: BaseExpr -> exists a. Expr a`](https://richarde.dev/papers/2021/exists/exists.pdf) :)

Comment: @Iceland_jack Oh, we're going to actually get existentials directly in the type system? Sweet!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an existential wrapper

```
{-# Language PolyKinds                #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications         #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

--
--   Exists @ExprType :: (ExprType -> Type) -> Type
--
type Exists :: forall k. (k -> Type) -> Type
data Exists f where
  Exists :: f x -> Exists f
```

and return `Exists Expr`

```
translate :: BaseExpr -> Exists @ExprType Expr
translate (BaseExprVar id)
  = Exists (ExprVar id)
translate (BaseExprNest expr)
  | Exists a <- translate expr
  = Exists (ExprNest a)
```

This uses [pattern guards](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13) to unpack the existential type

> *pattern guards* are of the form `p <- e`, where `p` is a pattern (see Section 3.17) of type `t` and `e` is an expression type `t1`. They succeed if the expression `e` matches the pattern `p`, and introduce the bindings of the pattern to the environment.
>
> [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13)

and is equivalent to these

```
translate (BaseExprNest expr) = case translate expr of
  Exists a -> Exists (ExprNest a)
```

```
{-# Language ViewPatterns #-}

translate (BaseExprNest (translate -> Expr a)) = Exists (ExprNest a)
```

But try it with `let` or `where` and it won't work.

References

- [Stitch: The Sound Type-Indexed Type Checker](https://richarde.dev/papers/2018/stitch/stitch.pdf)
- [An Existential Crisis Resolved](https://richarde.dev/papers/2021/exists/exists.pdf)

Comment: What extension does the `@ExprType` syntax come from?

Comment: That uses `{-# Language TypeApplications #-}` which allows you to overrid the visibility of type arguments. That means you can explicitly instantiate polymorphic types and kinds `length @[] @Bool [True, True]`

Comment: Ok, so with the extension enabled it still dies with: 

`error: parse error on input ‘::’` for `type Exists :: forall k. (k -> Type) -> Type`

Also if I comment out that line, it dies with:

`Cannot apply function of kind ‘(* -> *) -> *’ to visible kind argument ‘ExprType’`
for `translate :: BaseExpr -> Exists @ExprType Expr`

Comment: I think you need `StandaloneKindSignatures`

Comment: Thanks! Yes that + `PolyKinds` did the trick

Comment: Can you explain this? `Exists a <- translate expr`

Comment: I expanded on it in my answer

Comment: PolyKinds is essential to having `Exists` work on `Expr` because your type is indexed by a promoted datatype. It would be possible to define `data ExistsExpr where ExistsExpr :: Expr x -> ExistsExpr` but it's better to show a general pattern

Answer (score 5):

The reason why this fails is, because you're making a promise you can't keep.
The type of translate is `BaseExpr -> Expr a`,  so you're really saying "If you give me a `BaseExpr`, I will give you an `Expr a` for *any type `a` that you want*".
GHC complains, because you don't actually do this. If you call `translate` with a `BaseExprVar`, you won't actually get an `Expr a` for any type a, but you get an `Expr Var`.

To solve this, you can create an existential wrapper, as explained in @iceland_jack's answer.
The type `BaseExpr -> Exists @ExprType Expr` really means "If you give me a `BaseExpr`,  I will give you an `Expr a` for *some a, that I determine*.", which is exactly what your function does.

Answer (score 3):

### Why doesn't your original code work?

This type cannot work:

```
translate :: BaseExpr -> Expr a
```

Remember what type variables *mean* in Haskell. This type for `translate` is saying "for any type `a` the caller of `translate` chooses, it will take a `BaseExpr` and turn it into an `Expr a`".

So if I want to pass `BaseExprVar "variableName"` to `translate` and receive an `Expr Nest`, I should be able to do that; I'll just choose `a` to be `Nest`. It doesn't matter that this particular `BaseExpr` is just a variable, not a nested expression, and there is no value of type `Expr Nest` that faithfully represents this. With a polymorphic GADT as a return type, that's not **my** problem, it's `translate`'s problem, since the type for `translate` promised to be able to come up with such a value. `translate` can't force me to choose `Var` for `a`.

That isn't the type you want. You don't want the type of `Expr` that is returned to be chosen by the *caller* of `translate`, you want it to be chosen by the *implementation* of `translate` (so it can return whatever type is appropriate to the contents of the `BaseExpr`).

To have the implementation of a function choose a type parameter, you need to either use an existential wrapper, or use higher-rank types and continuation passing.

### Existential wrapper

```
data SomeExpr
  where SomeExpr :: Expr a -> SomeExpr

translate :: BaseExpr -> SomeExpr
translate (BaseExprVar id) = Some (ExprVar id)
translate (BaseExprNest expr)
  = case translate expr of
      Some e -> Some (ExprNest e)
```

Notice that the type parameter of `Expr` does *not* appear in the type for `translate`, so a caller of `translate` doesn't need to specify what it should be.

To use the output of `translate`, you will need to pattern match on the `Some` constructor, which will give you a value of type `Expr a` for some unknown `a` (as opposed to the original attempt at `translate`, which gives you a value of type `Expr a` for some particular `a` that you choose). Inside the pattern match, you therefore have to handle any possible value of `a`, and the resulting value cannot have a type that depends on `a` (we're only allowed to "see" it inside the pattern match).

You can see an example of this above in the recursive call; `translate expr` returned `Some Expr`, but what we needed to wrap up in the `ExprNest` constructor is `Expr a`. By pattern matching on `Some`, we get the contained `Expr a`, which we can then put inside the `ExprNest` constructor to get a value of type `Expr Nest`. Then we hide that back in a `Some` constructor, and finally have the right type to return from `translate`.

You can of course also generalise the existential wrapper so that it works on more types than just `Expr`, as shown in @Iceland_jack's answer. There's nothing special to the form I've used here; it is itself just another use of GADT syntax (to embed a value with a type parameter that isn't exposed in the overall type). A general one is nice, but often you'll want some type class constraints on the hidden type so that you have more things you can *do* with the value when you pattern match on it, so you'll need to get more complicated to make a type general enough to reuse any time you need an existential wrapper.

### Higher-rank types

The other way to handle the requirement for `translate` to return different types based on the data it is processing, is to use higher rank types. For this, you'll need the `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` extension.

```
translate :: BaseExpr -> (forall a. Expr a -> r) -> r
translate (BaseExprVar id) handler = handler (ExprVar id)
translate (BaseExprNest expr) handler
  = handler (translate expr ExprNest)
```

Here, instead of using an extra wrapper type to "hide" the type variable, we restructure `translate` so that it takes a "handler function" for `Expr`s. Now `translate` doesn't return any form of `Expr` at all, rather it makes one, passes it to `handler`, and returns what the handler returns.

Why does this work? The trick is that `handler` is required to be passed to `translate` **as a polymorphic function**. The nested `forall a.` inside the type of one of `translate`'s arguments means that the caller doesn't choose `a` like it normally would, instead the caller is required to pass a function that works for *any* possible `a`. The code of the handler function is similar to the "inside of the pattern match" in the existential wrapper version; it has to handle any possible `a` and can't return anything whose type depends on `a`.

Because the caller had to pass a `handler` that works for any `a`, the code for `translate` can use it at any type it likes, including at different types on different branches. So the first case for `translate` can pick `Var` and use `handler` as `Expr Var -> r`, while the second case can pick `Nest` and use handler as `Expr Nest -> r`.

Note a subtlety in the second case. Now when `translate` needs to recursively call itself, it needs to pass a "handler function". We could try passing the handler we received in from the top, but that's not right. We're supposed to be calling that handler only once on the *complete* `Expr`, not calling it at every level of the `BaseExpr`. And besides, that would only give us an `r`, which is not what we need to wrap up in the `ExprNest` constructor. Instead we need to realise that `ExprNest` is *itself* a function of type `forall a. Expr a -> Expr Nest`, which fits with the type we need for handler functions! Translating the nested expression with the `ExprNest` constructor as the handler will translate whatever is in it, and then feed it to the constructor, returning us the complete `Expr Nest` value we need to feed to the top level handler.

In this particular example the higher rank version ended up using less boilerplate than the existential wrapper version. That's often the case, but a possible downside is it makes you restructure some of your calling code into continuation passing form; you can't just call `translate` and then use the resulting value, you have to construct a function for what you *would* do with a translated expression if you had one, and then pass that function to `translate`. Sometimes that coding style is harder to read/write.

Comment: Minor point, `Expr Bool` wouldn't kind check because the argument is not a `Type`!

Comment: @Iceland_jack Of course. *headdesk* I was thinking of the non-DataKinds style where you have `data Var` and `data Nest`, and the GADT parameter is of kind `Type`. I've reworded the paragraph; in principle my point still applies, just the examples of what `translate :: BaseExpr -> Expr a` claims to be able to do that it obviously cannot are less dramatic.